# multiple step anonymous functions

Tags: matlab

I have a rather complicated function the I would like to write as an anonymous function.

It looks something like this:

```
function Answer = MatlabFunction(x)
a=4*x;
b=sin(a);
c=cos(b);
Answer = c;
```

I don't know how to put this into an anonymous function however.  Is there a way to do this without writing it as several cascading functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

Either, you save your function `MatlabFunction` on the Matlab path, and define your anonymous function as

```
myFun = @MatlabFunction;
```

Or, you define the function directly as

```
myFun = @(x)cos(sin(4*x));
```

Comment: Is there a different way?  I want to set the function want to change parts of the function at each cycle in a for loop, so I can't use an external file.  My actual function is much more complicated so I can't just combine it into one line.

Comment: @Brian: I answered your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673112/change-matlab-function-in-loop/3673185#3673185

Comment: You could pass several arbitrary chosen function handles to your 'worker' function.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is notorious for not supporting multiple step anonymous functions. There existing however some ugly tricks to circumvent this limitation. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50195-is-it-possible-to-write-several-statements-into-an-anonymous-function presents a few ones, e.g:

> An if/else can be coded in function form by using:
>
> ```
> FHEXEC = @(FH) FH();
> FHSELECT = @(TF,CONDITION) TF(CONDITION==[true,false]);
> IF = @(CONDITION,TRUEFUNC,FALSEFUNC) FHEXEC( FHSELECT([TRUEFUNC,FALSEFUNC],CONDITION) )
> ```