# Change Matlab function in loop

Tags: matlab

I want to make a slight change to a MATLAB function at each step in a for loop.  My function is too complicated to write as anonymous.  Is there any way to change an m-file function at each step?

Additional Info:
My function is an equations with 8 inputs and infinitely many solutions.  I want set 7 of the inputs and then use fsolve to find the 8th.  vary some of these 7 fixed inputs in a for loop so that I can create a graph of the solutions to this equation.

Comment: Can you provide any more detail about the type of change you'd like to make?

Comment: You do not need using an anonimous function for this kind of problem! Use just a wrapper function wich parametrizes your 8-Input function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make an example with two inputs, of which you want to change one. Since you claim your function is really complicated, let's write it into a file called `complicated.m`, which we save on the Matlab path.

```
function out = complicated(v1,v2,x)

out = v1*x-v2*x.^2;
```

Say we want to change `v1` and `v2` at every iteration in the loop and find a root of the polynomial and plot it

```
figure,hold on
for v1 = 1:5
   for v2 = 1:5
      %# define the function
      myFun = @(x)complicated(v1,v2,x);
      %# find the roots
      fzero(myFun,1)
      %# plot the function
      plot(-5:0.1:5,myFun(-5:0.1:5))
   end
end
```