# fsolve for solution != 0

Tags: matlab

I want to solve an equation for a different value in each cycle of a for loop.  I usually include the value that I am solving for in the m-file function but I can't change the m file at each cycle in the for loop.  Is there a way to solve the use fsolve but for a value !=0.

Comment: Incidentally, this seems to be essentially the same question as your previous one (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3673112/129570); it's considered bad form to ask the same question multiple times.  Just re-edit your previous question if you're still having problems on the exact same topic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html).  So if your paramterised function is:

```
function y = f(x, c)
...
end
```

then you can iterate over different parameters thus:

```
for c = 0:10
    fsolve(@(x)f(x,c), x0);
end
```

(Untested)

Comment: This is essentially correct, but if the goal is to solve for various right hand sides in fsolve, then the loop might look effectively like this: for i = 1:numel(rhs),result(i) = fsolve(@(x)f(x) - rhs(i), x0);end

Comment: @woodchhips: Yes, I suppose so!  I had assumed that one could incorporate the RHS constant into the function itself, but your method is better.