# To do beta reduction in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, lambda, lambda-calculus

**How can you do a beta reduction like the following in Matlab?**

[image]

My goal is to avoid duplicate assignments and lazy-evaluate things -- perhaps related to the question [multiple step anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673030/multiple-step-anonymous-functions).

Apparently, most functional features only supported in [Matlab2013B](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/functional-programming.html).

Comment: Your link about functional programming refers to the symbolic toolbox, not to standard matlab. There is some limited support for functional programming in matlab itself ([anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), [mapping](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) functions to arrays. Is that enough for you?

Comment: @hhh Can you please clarify why Dan's answer is not suitable? It seems to be alright for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean:

```
x = 3;
f = @(y)(x+x*y);
```

Now `f(y)` is the function `3+3*y`.

So you could put this in a loop for example:

```
f = {};
for x = 1:5
   f{x} = @(y)(x+x*y);
end;
```

And then find `f(2)` for each of those values of `x`

```
cellfun(@(y)y(2), f)

ans =   
    3    6    9   12   15
```

Comment: @hhh I don't understand how that is related? Please post the link.

Comment: @hhh Have you turned on MuPAD? Do you have the symbolic toolbox? I still don't see the relevance to your OP

Comment: @hhh you can do an if statement: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/category/functional-programming/

Comment: You meant something like `iif     = @(varargin) varargin{2*find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}(); hh=@(x)iif(x==1, x, 0); hh(1);` works but not `hh(1000)`?!

Comment: @hhh Are you trying to check if a number is `1`? Then you should have used `hh=@(x)iif(x==1, x, true, 0);`, the `true` I added is the `else` clause. I still don't see what any of this has to do with your OP. Surely my answer answers your actual question about how to make that lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate Dan's answer, this is what I get in Octave:

```
octave:1> f = @(x) @(y) x + y
f =
   @(x) @(y) x + y

octave:2> g = f (2)
g =
   @(y) x + y

octave:3> g (3)
ans =  5
```

But I do not know about Matlab...